# FabricJS - Canvas won't re-render after object:hover event

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

I have used 'piggyback' to be able to catch object:hover events mentioned here: https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/wiki/Working-with-events

Assume standard setup and these events:

```
canvas.on('object:over', function(e) {
    // some manipulation with e.target here, will execute on hover as expected
    canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas);
});
canvas.on('after:render', function() {
    // code here wont execute on hover but only after other action which evokes render, such as click and drag of object
})
```

Is there other way to force rerendering the canvas(es) on mouse hover of an object?

If you wonder what is my goal, I want to highlight objects on mouse over, very similar to something like this: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/labs/html5-canvas-world-map-svg-path-with-kineticjs/index.php

Thank you very much for help!

Comment: What's wrong with `canvas.renderAll()` in "object:over" callback?

Comment: Oh, I tried using canvas.renderAll() instead of canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas) and it works. Sorry for false alert,  I just followed techniques from tutorials on the web where canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas) is mostly used. I still don't really understand what is bind function supposed to do (yes, I have read documentation, but still has no clue ;). If you can clarify it, I will appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: It binds function to a certain "this value" but doesn't actually execute it. Take a look at Function.prototype.bind description on MDC

Comment: Thanks again, I somehow missed the link to MDN.